# integration of $\frac{x^{2}-3x+2}{x-3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have completed the integration up until I'm left with

$$\frac{x^{2}+9x+9}{2}+3x-9+2\ln|x-3|+C$$

but the answer I'm looking for is 
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2+2\ln|x-3|+C$$

So my question is how do I get there?

Comment: The $9$ of course gets absorbed into $C$. But how did you end up with $\frac{x^2+9x+9}2+3x$ in the first place?

Comment: I did a u-sub with u=x-3 and then turned the fraction into $\frac{u^2+3u+2}{u}$

Comment: I think you just made a small error: $(x-3)^2=x^2-6x+9$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{x^{2}-3x+2}{x-3}= \frac{x(x-3)}{x-3}+\frac{2}{x-3}$$

$$= x+\frac{2}{x-3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the substitution you mention in the comments, we have

$$u=x-3\implies x=u+3\implies\mathrm dx=\mathrm du$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x-3}\,\mathrm dx&=\int\frac{(u+3)^2-3(u+3)+2}u\,\mathrm du\\[1ex]
&=\int\frac{u^2+3u+2}u\,\mathrm du\\[1ex]
&=\int\left(u+3+\frac2u\right)\,\mathrm du\\[1ex]
&=\frac{u^2}2+3u+2\ln|u|+C\\[1ex]
&=\frac{(x-3)^2}2+3(x-3)+2\ln|x-3|+C\\[1ex]
&=\frac{x^2-6x}2+3x+2\ln|x-3|+C\\[1ex]
&=\frac{x^2}2+2\ln|x-3|+C\\[1ex]
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

If we look carefully the degree of polynomial in the numerator is more than the degree of denominator. Therefore, We need to divide the numerator by denominator.

◾ (x²-3x+2)/(x-3) = x + 2/(x-3)

Next step is to integrate both the sides

▪ Int{(x²-3x+2)/(x-3)} = Int{x} + Int{2/(x-3)}

and we got your answer!!!

▪  Int{(x²-3x+2)/(x-3)} = x²/2 + 2lg|x-3| + C

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).